# wx.Image constructor shows popup instead of raising an exception

Tags: python, wxpython

When I run this Python code:

```py
import io, wx

with open("imgs/ad.png", "rb") as fid:
    img_stream = io.BytesIO(fid.read())
try:
    img = wx.Image(img_stream, type=wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNM)
except:
    pass
```

it results in a message box saying "Error: This is not a PNM file." instead of raising an exception. Is it possible to have **wx** raise an exception instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rolf-of-Saxony pointed out, the message box is due to [wxPython logging](https://docs.wxpython.org/log_classes_overview.html). Two basic options for suppressing it are temporary creation of `the wx.LogNull()` object

```py
import io
import wx

with open("imgs/Olympic_flag.svg", "rb") as fid:
    img_stream = io.BytesIO(fid.read())
noLog = wx.LogNull()
img = wx.Image(img_stream)
if img.IsOk():
    pass
else:
    pass
del noLog
```

or calling wx.Log.EnableLogging()

```py
import io
import wx

wx.Log.EnableLogging(False)
img = wx.Image(img_stream)
if img.IsOk():
    pass
else:
    pass
wx.Log.EnableLogging(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Test the result within the `try ... except ...` statement, raising an error if required, manually.
The `wx.Image` is handling its own exception to be able to report the error in a `wx.Message`

```
import io, wx
app = wx.App()

with open("a.png", "rb") as fid:
    img_stream = io.BytesIO(fid.read())

try:
    img = wx.Image(img_stream, type=wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNM)
    if img.IsOk():
        conv_result = True
    else:
        raise Exception("Image conversion error!")
except Exception as e:
    conv_result = False

print(conv_result)
```

Comment: How do I prevent the message box then?

Comment: I'd guess you would have to dig into the gory guts of `wx.Log` to temporarily redirect `wx.LogMessage`. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the pointers! https://docs.wxpython.org/log_classes_overview.html is exactly where I needed to look. I just have not realized what was nature of that message box.